# I am getting error 3802 while running a SQL query in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I am running the following query.

```
create multiset volatile table table1 as (
select
a.variable1,
a.variable2, 
b.variable3, 
b.variable4, 
c.variable5, 
c.variable6, 
d.variable7,
d.variable8

from data1 as a
left join data2 as b
on a.ID1=b.ID1 and a.date1=b.date1
left join data3 as c
on a.ID1=c.ID1 and a.date1=c.date1
left join data4 as d
on a.ID1=d.ID1 and a.date1=d.date1
where a.variable1>100 and a.varaiable2 in ('A','B'))
with data primary index (id1,id2,id3,date1) on commit preserve rows ;
```

I am getting the error- 
PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.08] [Error 3802] [SQLState 42S02] Database 'd' does not exist."
]

However, I am able to run the query select * from data4 which means that data4 does exist.

It will be great if you guys can help me find out what's generating this error.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly, your primary index relies on columns that do not exist in the final set.

Comment: Obviously this isn't the actual query. The error indicates something in the query makes Teradata think you are using d as a database reference instead of a table alias. Perhaps there is an extra period somewhere in the real query, like d.col.z which would be interpreted as database d table col column z?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a table with a subselect regardless of the type of the table, in order to put columns as PIs outside the parenthesis you have to select them inside otherwise the parsing engine won't know what are those columns and from where to get them.

In this case, you need:

```
A.ID1 AS ID1,
B.ID1 AS ID2,
C.ID1 AS ID3,
A.DATE1 AS DATE1,
```

Try this:

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE TABLE1 AS (
SELECT
A.ID1 AS ID1,
B.ID1 AS ID2,
C.ID1 AS ID3,
A.DATE1 AS DATE1,
A.VARIABLE1,
A.VARIABLE2, 
B.VARIABLE3, 
B.VARIABLE4, 
C.VARIABLE5, 
C.VARIABLE6, 
D.VARIABLE7,
D.VARIABLE8
FROM DATA1 AS A
LEFT JOIN DATA2 AS B
ON A.ID1=B.ID1 AND A.DATE1=B.DATE1
LEFT JOIN DATA3 AS C
ON A.ID1=C.ID1 AND A.DATE1=C.DATE1
LEFT JOIN DATA4 AS D
ON A.ID1=D.ID1 AND A.DATE1=D.DATE1
WHERE A.VARIABLE1>100 AND A.VARIABLE2 IN ('A','B')
)
WITH DATA
PRIMARY INDEX (ID1,ID2,ID3,DATE1)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```